# Django: redirect to the same url with an appended querystring

Tags: python, django, redirect

How to I redirect to the same url but append a query_string to it? ie. redirect from "base.com/amt" to "base.com/amt/?ref=blah&id=blah"

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^amt/$', RedirectView.as_view(reverse_lazy('amt')), {'SSL':True}),
url(r'^amt/?ref_source=AMT&ref_id=PC', 'core.views.show_amt_page', {'SSL':True}, name='amt'),
```

in this case I want to go from "^amt/$" to "^amt/?ref_source=AMT..."

Once the redirect is done, I need to execute `show_amt_page()` int `views.py`

If there's a better way to do it, can someone explain how that can be done so django executes `show_amt_page()` in `views.py`?

Comment: The query string is not part of the url definition, so your second url is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not handled by the url patterns, therefore you can only have one url pattern for `/amt/`, which will handle requests with and without the get parameters.

```
url(r'^amt/', 'core.views.show_amt_page', {'SSL':True}, name='amt'),
```

In the `show_amt_page` view, you can check for the get parameters in `request.GET`, and return a redirect response if necessary.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def show_amt_page(request, SSL):
    if 'ref_source' not in request.GET:
        return redirect('amt/?ref_source=AMT&ref_id=PC')
    # rest of view goes here
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

in urls.py

```
...

    url(r'^$', pages.home, name='home'),
...
```

Function tu build an urls with GET parameters

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
def build_url(*args, **kwargs):
    get = kwargs.pop('get', {})
    url = reverse(*args, **kwargs)
    if get:
        url += '?' + urllib.urlencode(get)
    return url
```

Use example

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(build_url('home', get={'ref_source': 'AMT','ref_id':'PC'}))

return HttpResponseRedirect(build_url('home', get={'opcion': '1'}))
```